# UppercuT project output directory configuration

Tags: build

I'm attempting to set up a build system for the project I'm working on and I've added Uppercut.

My solution has a number of projects and everything seems to be working fine, although all of the binaries after the build has finished are placed in one folder under the code_drop folder and not in individual folders based on project name as I would expect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually solved this issue now by using [PublishedApplications](http://nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications)

Comment: If you have a problem where all `Content` marked as `Copy Always` is copied to the root folder and not hierarchically see my answer to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732824/customise-build-build-output-for-specific-projects).