# Customise Build Build Output for Specific Projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2013

I have a solution which contains a number of 2 windows console projects, 1 website project and 20 class libraries.

I want TFS 2013 to push to the drop folder only the windows console and website projects to the drop folder.

I am looking for a folder structure similar to below.

```
DropFolder
    - App1
    - App2
    - Website1
```

How is the best way to configure TFS to allow this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have ended up using the nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications for all the projects that I want to be published. This copies the projects into a _PublishedApplications folder. So that I have a folder structure like this

```
DropFolder
    _PublishedApplications
        - App1
        - App2
    _PublishedWebsites
        - Website1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The default template has `Solution Specific Build Outputs` property under Process tab Advanced section. 
  [image: Solution Specific Build Outputs]
- Alternatively you can let [MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983319/147211) control your build flow.

**Update:**

- The ultimate solution seems implementing NuGet's 
  [PublishedApplications](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications)

Comment: The solution I was looking for came from another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12741336/183892). Using a nugget package to create the targets that puts the web projects in _PublishedApplications.

Comment: That's even better. I've updated the answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [PublishedApplications](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications) NuGet package as well, but have encountered an issue. If referenced libraries had `Content` marked as `Copy Always` all content would be copied to the root folder and not hierarchically. For example if you have following projects and structure (some files omitted for brevity):

```
PublishLib
    test
        TextFile1.txt (marked as Content/CopyAlways)

TestPublishTargetApp - references PublishLib
    targets
        Microsoft.Application.targets
```

When team build is done this is the content of `_PublishedApplications\TestPublishTargetApp` folder:

```
PublishLib.dll
TestPublishTargetApp.exe
TestPublishTargetApp.exe.config
TestPublishTargetApp.pdb
TextFile1.txt
```

And what I expected was:

```
test\TextFile1.txt
PublishLib.dll
TestPublishTargetApp.exe
TestPublishTargetApp.exe.config
TestPublishTargetApp.pdb
```

After fiddling around a bit with `Microsoft.Application.targets` I was able to get what I wanted by changing last `<Copy SourceFiles` (original commented out):

```
    <!--<Copy SourceFiles="@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways)"
      DestinationFolder="$(ExeProjectOutputDir)"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
      Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
      RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"/>-->

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways)"
      DestinationFiles = "@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways->'$(ExeProjectOutputDir)\%(TargetPath)')"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="false"
      Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
      RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"/>
```

I am not sure if this is useful to anyone else, but for me this was essential change, plus `PublishedApplications` NuGet package was not changed since 2014 (seems like abandoned project).