# How to avoid mixed output files with MSBuild?

Tags: powershell, build, msbuild

I have a C# big project in Visual Studio 2013 that is formed by:

- 3 Web projects
- 2 Windows Services project
- 14 Dlls projects
- 2 Test projects
- 1 Database Project (.sqlproj)

As you can guess the final files are:

- 3 Web Projects
- 2 Windows Services
- Database

I build it with msbuild.exe invoked from PowerShell.

```
$msbuild="C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
$option0 = 'FOO.sln /t:Clean,Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Outdir=$outputdir'
iex "$msbuild $option0" | tee C:\TFS\Oscar\Build\oscar.txt
```

The project builds and in the **output folder** I have a nice directory called **_PublishedWebsites** that contains the three websites, one in each directory. From here it wouldn't be complicated to deploy to servers using PowerShell.

In outputdir I have my **FooDB.dacpac** so I can easily use **sqlpackage** to deploy it to SQL Server.

**My problem** is with Windows Services. Instead of being in a folder they are in output folder, mixed with all DLLs, sqlproj files, test files.

**Is there any way of having them in a folder similar to "_PublishedWebsites"?**

I can copy all files to each windows service folder on deploy and will work... but feels wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES!  You can actually use MSDeploy which is the underlying technology for WebDeploy to create a similar deployment package for a Windows service or scheduled task.

The basic steps are

- extend MSBuild to zip up the files into a package
- add pre/post sync commands
- create a deploy cmd to execute the package

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/18/deploy-non-web-apps-with-msdeploy/

Answer (score 1):

We've been using the nuget package [PublishedApplications](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications/) in in our Windows Service projects (which are actually just Console Apps using [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) ).

As a result, we get a nicely packaged app in the output folder `{OutDir}/_PublishedApplications/{appName}` (next to `{OutDir}/PublishedWebSites`) for those services.

I'm still looking for a way to get a similar behavior for `*.sqlproj` projects ...

Comment: If you have a problem where all `Content` marked as `Copy Always` is copied to the root folder and not hierarchically see my answer to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732824/customise-build-build-output-for-specific-projects).